# How to set server side pagination in Angular material Table using token

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

here i have a issue while working with angular paginator . here i am getting data like below

**Response One:**

```
{
    "Tabledata": [
      {
        "firstName":"Samuel",
        "lastName":"Smith"
      },
      {
        "firstName":"Sanu",
        "lastName":"Smith"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "RecordsCount": 2,
        "token": "JhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
    }
}
```

**Response Two:**
I am getting total records count as 50

```
 { 
    'RecordsCount' : 50
  }
```

Now in the initial call the i am calling api and the api format is below

**Initial Call**

```
http://some api.com/data?searchParams=&pageSize=2&token=
```

After calling this i will get response like below

```
{
        "Tabledata": [
          {
            "firstName":"Samuel",
            "lastName":"Smith"
          },
          {
            "firstName":"Sanu",
            "lastName":"Smith"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
            "RecordsCount": 2,
            "token": "JhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
        }
    }
```

and after pressing the next button the api should initiate another http call and use this token and send it params for the same api
like below

**2nd call**

http://some api.com/data?searchParams=&pageSize=2&token=JhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9

After this call i will get again same response but here token changes

```
{
            "Tabledata": [
              {
                "firstName":"Samuel",
                "lastName":"Smith"
              },
              {
                "firstName":"Sanu",
                "lastName":"Smith"
              }
            ],
            "paging": {
                "RecordsCount": 2,
                "token": "abcd"
            }
        }
```

And if i press next again in the 3rd api call is should use the 2nd response token as param for the 3rd call and it will give some token and if user presses Prev then it should use that tocken and send as param here this i am unable to solve this in front end i wrote like

```
 <mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" [length]="totalLength"  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" (page)="PageEvents($event)"></mat-paginator>


PageEvents(event: PageEvent){
    this.pageNumber = 1;
    const pageSize = +event.pageSize; 
    const currentPage = +event.pageIndex + 1; 
    const pagination = {
      searchQuery: '',
      pageSize: pageSize,
      token: ''
    };
    if(currentPage > this.pageNumber) {

     

      console.log('next button',pageSize,currentPage)
    } else {
     
      console.log('prev button',pageSize,currentPage)

    }

  }
```

**`totalLength= 50`**

here my issues

1. Although i am sending totallenght ui disabling my prev and next button
2. How can i achieve this pagination
   [image]

Comment: what is that token for? user authentication?

Comment: Just pagination token for getting next records not  for authenctication

Comment: Which api method are you using to get data?

Comment: POST method is used for that

Comment: No, I wanted to know all about that endpoint. Which parameters is it taken?

Comment: What's the issue? We cannot tell you how to use the token. You need to indicate what request the API is expecting to get the token (query param, request body,...)

Comment: @yurzui please check the updated question

Comment: @David please check the updated question

Comment: if you interpolate {{totalLength}} in HTML of your component, lets say just below your mat-paginator component ... does it shows 50 ? basically have you declared the member variable of your class totalLength and assign it value on your api response ?

Comment: no but using property binding is should display right @bron1010

Comment: yes @ShyamNair unless you check the actual value used in template, your prev and next button might stay disabled.

Comment: yeah now it is disabled but how can i enable @bron1010

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-paginator
      [length]="total"
      [pageSize]="pageSize"
      [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
      [showFirstLastButtons]="isShowFirstLastBtn"
      (page)="onChangePage($event)"
    ></mat-paginator>
```

Then in your component file, you can receive the page event as:

```
 private subscription = new Subscription();
   ngOnInIt() {
      // subscribe to the service for page data
      this.subscription = this.service.tableDataAction$.subscribe(resp => do initial table render);

}

    onChangePage(event: PageEvent) {
     const pageSize = +event.pageSize; // get the pageSize
     const currentPage = +event.pageIndex + 1; // get the current page
    
     this.service.paginationData(pageSize, currentPage); // call the service
    }

  ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }

in service:
   

    private paginationSubject = new Subject<{}>();
       tableDataAction$ = this.paginationSubject.asObservable();
        paginationData(pageSize: number, currentPage: number) {
            // get or post whatever you prefer, get is more correct choice
           this.http.get(url + queryParams).subscribe(
             (resp) => this.paginationSubject.next(resp)),
             (err) => catchError // handle error
          }
```

P.S: To get total count of pagination you should also sent the total Count of the data present with the current data so that in pagination you can show item n of total

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It is recommended to avoid using a token for pagination.
You can simply use `skip` and `limit`. Something that you are currently using is `pageSize` which works as limit and
let us call a new param `currentPage` as skip.
Anyways moving ahead with token, the implementation logic is as below.

**Step 1**

You will need following member variables for component in which paginator is present.

```
  defaultPayload = {
    searchParams : "",
    pageSize : 2,
    currentPage : 1,
    token : ""
  };
  totalLength = 0;
```

the `defaultPayload` is argument to your service through which new data comes in.
You need `currentPage` at angular service level for `tokenMap` implementation will explain
in sometime.
`totalLength` as you have already binded it to mat-paginator.

Before moving ahead, you have a question about `totalLength`. As shown in image your totalLength
is 2, As the `pageSize` is 10, the functionality of next and previous are disabled. It makes sense too. If your response `RecordsCount` is 50, it will show up if you have set the member variable as the following step demonstrates.

**Step 2 On load**

Let's say we are subscribed to the api service as below in ngInit

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataService(this.defaultPayload)
    .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.defaultPayload.token = paging['token'];
          this.totalLength = paging['RecordsCount'];
        },
        err => {}
    );
  }
```

On response, we are :

- setting default token for first api onload
- setting response `RecordsCount` in totalLength (which you might be expecting 50, but its 2)
- Every time an event occurs in step 3, we will set the data on response here itself.

**Step 3 On event**

```
PageEvents(event){
    console.log("event", event, this.defaultPayload);
    const pageSize = event.pageSize; 
    const currentPage = event.pageIndex + 1; 
    this.defaultPayload.pageSize = pageSize;
    this.defaultPayload.currentPage = currentPage;
    this.getDataService(this.defaultPayload)
}
```

Note We are just resetting our request payload again as per new event and
make a service call.

**Step 4 Service**

let say we have some service as follows that is responsible for
providing data. We need to maintain some kind of storage for token. you might
use localstorage or simply an object as below whatever suits your need. This is
needed because we need to maintain tokens for all (old) prev and (new) next page events.

```
 constructor() { 
        this.tokenMap = {};
    }
  
    getDataService({...options, currentPage}){
        options.token = findToken(currentPage)
        //http request using {options}
        //on response setToken
        this.setTokenMap(options.currentPage, response['token])
        return responseData
    }

    findToken(page){
        return this.tokenMap[page || 1] || "";
    }

    setTokenMap(page, token){
        this.tokenMap[page] = token;
    }
```

This service will find the token while making an api call, and also set the
new token as per currentPage, hence you don't have to bother about token
in component.
This will separate your concerns of the token logic and
component paginator data.

Comment: here i have only pagesize i.e number of records per page and token in that case ?

Comment: @ShyamNair , you can implement other things  as recommended in answer